# How many equivalent expressions can be derived from the associative law for addition for n summands?

Tags: summation, proof-explanation, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics, associativity

The associative law for addition states:

$a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c$

Considering only this law for the sum $a_{1}+...+a_{n}$ of $n$ numbers $a_{1}+...+a_{n}$. How many equivalent expressions exist?

---

**Some context**

I restarted reading Michael Spivak's *Calculus* and, just for fun, came up with this problem (I didn't check if maybe it's one of the exercises in the book...).

I am not a professional mathematician and my mathematical abilities are very rusty (to say the least) since I went to college, so I would ask to whoever wants to help me reach a solution to keep this in mind.

I don't understand how to reach a proof to this problem. If I manage to derive a formula, wouldn't I have to check with the pictorial representation of the sum whether it is right or not?

---

**My attempt at a solution**

So, I can start small, and say:

-> For $n=3$, the solution is $2$. Namely,

$(a_{1}+a_{2})+a_{3}\tag{1.1}$

$a_{1}+(a_{2}+a_{3})\tag{1.2}$

-> For $n=4$, the solution is $5$. Namely,

$((a_{1}+a_{2})+a_{3})+a_{4}\tag{2.1}$

$(a_{1}+(a_{2}+a_{3}))+a_{4}\tag{2.2}$

$a_{1}+((a_{2}+a_{3})+a_{4})\tag{2.3}$

$a_{1}+(a_{2}+(a_{3}+a_{4}))\tag{2.4}$

$(a_{1}+a_{2})+(a_{3}+a_{4})\tag{2.5}$

We can already see that when we plug in a new summand to the expressions in the previous solution, we obtain a valid equivalent expression for this number of elements. In addition to this, $2.3$ and $2.4$ are a mirror image of $2.1$ and $2.2$, respectively. So we can say that the solution for $n=4$ is two times the solution for $n=3$ plus something else.

-> When we plug in the fifth summand we have a n=3 case for each of the previous expressions. Following the previous reasoning, accounting for the mirror expressions, the solution for $n=5$ is going to be $5·2·2=20$.

From this, I think in cases where $n$ is odd, the solution is $2·f(n)$, where $f(n)$ is the product of all previous solutions. My suspicion is that, if $n$ is even, the solution is $2·f(n)+1$.

If this is true. How do I go about making sure of this without spending an eternity printing out expressions and comparing them?

If it isn't true. How did you disprove it?

Comment: It will be $14$, not $20$. You want the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number); see in particular the third application [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Comment: Spivak's chapter 2 (3rd ed) covers some ideas and techniques you'll find helpful here, including proof by induction.